# mongdb monk -Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am having the error : Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters. When I tried to use find query using IDs obtained in a previous query. I tried casting them as ObjectIds but it gives me the same error. Your kind help is greatly appreciated. The following is my code:

```
           var bookIds = []
           for(var j = 0; j < cart.length; j++){
               bookIds.push(cart[j].bookId);
           }
           bookCollection.find({_id:{$in:bookIds}}, {}, function(err, books){
                if(err !== null){
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send({"msg":"Add to cart error"});
                }   
                if(books){
                    console.log("new cart");
                    console.log(cart);
                    console.log(books);
                    res.json(books);
                }
                else{
                    res.send({"msg":"Add to cart error"});
                }
           });
```

content of cart:

```
[ { bookId: '5ac5cdf3532808df2e80281e', quantity: 3 },
  { bookId: '5ac5d30479705c2a30a0c235', quantity: 4 },
  { bookId: '5ac5cdfd532808df2e80281f', quantity: 1 },
  { bookId: '5ac5cfe379705c2a30a0c23', quantity: '2' } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast them they are already `ObjectId` when you store them as `ObjectId` or `ref` of other model.

```
const bookIds = cart.map({bookId} => bookId);
bookCollection.find({ "_id" :{ "$in": bookIds }})
.then(books => {
     console.log("new cart");
     console.log(cart);
     console.log(books);
     res.json(books);
})
.catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
     res.send({"msg":"Add to cart error"});
})
```

Comment: can you do me a favor by mentioning line where you are getting error. because the code is fine.

Comment: It worked, I found that my error is in some other line - var userId = req.session.userId; 

 userCollection.findOne({'_id':userId}, function(err, user){})

May I ask how do I fix this with the same error?

Comment: your `userId` variable is not a valid **mongoId**. so If you log it, you would know that it needs to be fixed

Comment: It gives me a string of ID, how should I modify it?

Comment: can you paste your string ID?
also try this code: 
`userCollection.findById(userId, function(err, user){})` This should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168382/discussion-between-muhammad-faizan-and-soulless).

Comment: bookCollection.find({ "_id" :{ "$in": bookIds }})

I fix the previous error with findById but the same error happens on the line above

Comment: you can do it this way then `const bookIds = [].map.call(cart, ({bookId} => bookId)`
this would suffice

Answer (score 0):

This is because _id must be type Mongoose.Types.ObjectId

To Resolve :

```
objectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

 for(var j = 0; j < cart.length; j++){
   bookIds.push(new objectId(cart[j].bookId));
 }
```