# How to find by string id using MongoDB, Node and Monk?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have a document on my collection that has the id "info". I can search on Mongo Atlas easily with `{_id: "info"}` filter, but when I try with Monk on Node, it tries to create the ObjectID and throw an error. How is the correct way of doing this search on Node?

Search using Atlas console:

[image]

```
const db = monk(url);
const rockets = db.get('rockets');

rockets.find({ _id: "info" }).then((docs) => { 
    console.log(docs);
})
```

**Throw Error:**

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
    at Function.createFromHexString
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongdb monk -Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686453/mongdb-monk-argument-passed-in-must-be-a-single-string-of-12-bytes-or-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out...

`.find({ '_id': { $eq: "info" } })`

Makes Monk stop trying to cast into ObjectID.